# How do I implement JDatePicker

Tags: java, datepicker

I am working with the latest release 1.3.4 of JDatePicker. How should it be implemented?

I get a compiler error: The constructor JDatePanelImpl(UtilDateModel) is undefined. The suggested fix is to: add argument to match JDatePanelImpl(DateModel, Properties). What should be passed in as the properties argument?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.*;
import org.jdatepicker.util.*;
import org.jdatepicker.*;

    //import org.jdatepicker.graphics.*;
class date2 {

    void GUI() {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(300, 300);
        f1.setVisible(true);

        Container conn = f1.getContentPane();
        conn.setLayout(null);

        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        //model.setDate(20,04,2014);
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);
        f1.add(datePicker);

    }

}
```

...Runner...

```
class testDate2 {

    public void main(String[] args) {

        date2 d1 = new date2();
        d1.GUI();

    }

}
```

Comment: See this --> `conn.setLayout(null);` <-- This be bad, don't do this. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: And see [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more details

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you are using 1.3.4, then the constructor requirements have changed...

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
//model.setDate(20,04,2014);
// Need this...
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
// Don't know about the formatter, but there it is...
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
```

[image]

Using this `AbstractFormatter`...

```
public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

    private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if (value != null) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
            return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i'm using Jdatepicker 1.3.4, as to test this i have use a null layout. This is for our final java project for the diploma level. Thank you for the help. Also can you suggest a way to add background image for the JFrame/JPanel?

Comment: The best way is to create a custom component extending from JPanel, override its paintComponent method and draw the image there. Search SO, there are plenty of examples

Comment: How do I get the date to a JLabel or Jtextfield?

Comment: have you tried `getDate`?  You'll probably want to use a `DateFormatter` and/or a `JFormattedField`

Comment: There's also a `JDateComponentFactory` which creates `JDatePickerImpl` and `JDatePanelImpl` objects, with the models and i18n properties already set. I'm a little unclear on whether the `JDatePanelImpl` constructor is intended to be called directly by clients at this point, since there's not great guidance in the docs on how to construct the i18n `Properties` it's using.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I went looking for something like that, but couldn't find anything (useful) and the only example I could find that worked used the implementation directly. I agree, it's a bit dirty and I wasn't happy doing so

Comment: Yeah, I had to dig around in the source to learn how to use it, since it's not documented anywhere—all the examples online are using the old pre-1.3.4 API. Usage: `JDatePanelImpl datePanel = (JDatePanelImpl) new JDateComponentFactory().createJDatePanel(); UtilCalendarModel model = (UtilCalendarModel) datePanel.getModel();`. This is a bit dirty in its own way, but I'm happier doing this than mucking around with the i18n Properties directly.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Yeah, it's still a bunch of hacking which shouldn't be needed.  I can't see anyway to set the model for a `JDatePanel` without casting it and you shouldn't have to cast it because that's the point of the factory and ... I'm going to use `JXDatePicker` instead :P

Comment: `AbstractFormatter` is serializable, so the `DateLabelFormatter` needs to either `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` or include `private static final long serialVersionUID`.

Comment: @NickGraham You know, in 16 years I've never "had" to include `serialVersionUID`, but then again, I don't use Eclipse, nor am I an exponent of Serialisation, as there are better solutions for most problems, but that's just me

Answer (score 6):

Just use properties in the constructor of `JDatePanelImpl`

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
```

Comment: Yes already done that. It's actually pretty good package by the way. I used it for many of my applications.

Comment: Are those the properties from java.util?