# What do these JDatePicker Properties do?

Tags: java, properties, datepicker

I recently viewed the following code in the context of implementing a JDatePicker in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794863/4547020).

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
//model.setDate(20,04,2014);
// Need this...
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
// Don't know about the formatter, but there it is...
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
```

I wanted to know what the properties Keys "text.month" and "text.year" do.  I tried implementing this code and say no change when omitting them.  Furthermore, I tried searching for a list of Keys in the Properties class and found nothing helpful.  Would anyone know what these property keys do or how I could find out if omitting them is acceptable?

Comment: Just guessing: maybe this represents a poor-mans solution regarding internalization; meaning: you don't hardcode the string "Today" in your application, because when the application is using a different language, for example German, the "today" field should better say "Heute" (German for "today"). That is the only explanation I can think of (and of course, when the String is still hardcoded in another piece of code, it doesn't help to use a property).

Answer (score 1):

These are for internationalization support. The `JDateComponentFactory` has code to load those from locale-dependent resource bundles in the JDatePicker distribution. I think you're supposed to use the factory instead of the constructor, and let it set up the properties appropriately so you aren't coupled to the key strings they're using.